# Permuting subgroups with the same finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose that we have a finitely generated residually finite group $G = \langle g_1,\ldots,g_r \rangle$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with finite index $m$. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism on $G$.

**Question**: What is the bound for the *smallest $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, such that $\phi ^n(H) = H$*?

**My thought so far**: We know that $G$ has at most $(m!)^r$ number of subgroups with index $m$, so $n \leq (m!)^r$. I was wondering if the bound can be improved, it seems unlikely for the automorphism to go through all the subgroups of this index. Is it possible to show that $n$ is bounded by a polynomial (or even linear function) in $m$, i.e. $ n = \mathcal{O}_r(m^d)$ for some $d$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing them out, $r$ is fixed and any dependency on $r$ is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G = \langle x,y,z \rangle = F_3$ be the free group on $3$ generators.  If $w = w(x,y)$ is any word in $x$ and $y$, then $x$, $y$, and $zw$ generate $F_3$ because $x$ and $y$ generate $w$ and thus from $zw$ and $x$ and $y$ one can recover $x$, $y$, and $z$. Thus the map

$$\phi: x,y,z \rightarrow x,y,zw$$

is an automorphism of $F_3$. Now let $\psi: G\rightarrow S_m$ be the map such that:

$$\psi(x) = (1,2), \psi(y) = (1,2,3,\ldots,n), \psi(z) = e.$$

This is surjective because the first two elements generate $S_m$.  Let $\sigma$ be any element of $S_m$. Then since $x$ and $y$ generate $S_m$, there is a word $w = w(x,y)$ such that $\psi(w) = \sigma$.  Let $\phi$ denote the automorphism of $G = F_3$ which fixes $x$ and $y$ and sends $z$ to $zw$ for this $w$. Let $H$ denote the stabilizer of $1$ under the action of $G$ given by $\psi$, and let $K$ denote the normal closure of $H$, which is the kernel of $\psi$. If $\phi^n(H) = H$, then certainly $\phi^n(K) = K$ as well. But $\phi(z) = e$ so $z \in K$, whereas

$$\phi(\psi^n(z)) = \phi(zw^n) = \psi(w^n) = \sigma^n.$$

Hence $\phi^n(z)$ lies in $K$ only if $\sigma^n = e$. Thus any bound on $n$ (for $r = 3$) in terms of $m$ also gives a bound for the order of any element $\sigma \in S_m$. But this order is not bounded polynomially in $m$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and explanation!! So we have to assume that the group $G$ has additional property for $n$ to be bounded by a polynomial. (Maybe the group itself needs to have polynomial growth)